# stack alignment armeabi-v7a

Tags: assembly, arm, clang, clang++

During my last project I had an uncommon issue, where sp was miss-aligned in an arm32 shared object.

llvm clang offers following flags to align the stack:

```
-mstack-alignment=n    // sets the alignment to n bytes
-mstackrealign         // forces the previous set alignment
```

after compilation with `n=16` the following `bfc` instruction appeared at the top of every function.

```
0x000007c8      1fd0c1e7       bfc sp, 0, 2
```

In my opinion this is not correct since this refers to 4 byte sp alignment.

However if I set `alignas(16) char buf[4]` at the beginning of a function, the alignment looks correct.

```
0x000007c8      1fd0c3e7       bfc sp, 0, 4
```

Anything I miss-understood about the clang flags?

(Small side note, for arm64 everything looks okay)

**Update 29.07
Minimal reproduce-able example:**

**test.cpp**

```
int my_func()
{
  return 1;
}
```

**Cmdline:**

```
armv7a-linux-androideabi23-clang++ test.cpp -shared -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign
```

**Clang version:**

Clang taken from Android NDK V23.1.7779620

However it is reproduce-able with different versions as well.
Complete path:

```
23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi23-clang++
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would probably be useful to include an [mre], with a simple program, compilation command-line options, and compiler version (and specify whether the code is C or C++, if it's not obvious). I haven't gotten the compiler to even generate a `BFC` as part of that.

Comment: added a minimal reproducible example